# Show that if both $M'$,$M''$ are finitely generated then so is $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M\rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. Show that if both $M'$, $M''$ are finitely-generated then so is $M$.

Comment: You forgot $M$ in the sequence. And what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: $M''\cong M/M'$ (if I put an $M$ between $M'$ and $M''$; guess that's what you wanted to type in!?).

Comment: You posted twice within a minute, both of which seem to be homework problems, without any hint of a personal attempt at solving the problem(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $u_1,\dots,u_m\in M''$ which generate it.  Since $\pi: M\to M''$ is onto, for each $i$ choose $x_1,\dots,x_m\in M$ so that $\pi(x_i)=u_i$.

Now, if $x\in M$, then $\pi(x)=\sum a_i u_i$ for some set of values $a_1,\dots,a_m\in R$.  Then $\pi(x-\sum a_ix_i) = \pi(x)-\sum a_i u_i = 0$, so $x-\sum a_ix_i\in \ker \pi$.

But $\ker\pi \cong M'$. Now use that $M'$ is also finitely generated to finish the proof.

Comment: In other words: preimages of a generating set for $M''$ and images of a generating set for $M'$ together make up a generating set for $M$.

Comment: Representatives of pre-images, of course, yes @HagenvonEitzen. (Preimages might not be finite.)